# Send parameters in trigger ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working on a pipeline and we have DEV,QA and UAT env, so we are trying to use a parameter in the linked service in order to change the conection to the different DB (based on the environment)

we also have different triggers to run the pipeline based on the environment so my question is, is there a way to add a parameter in the trigger, execute the pipeline and send the linked service to connect to a specific environment?

Comment: what database are you using and what kind of trigger have you setup. Please share more details of your setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have parameters to any type of triggers. Assuming you have a custom event trigger and SQL server as source, checkout the below example:

While creating SQL server linked service as a dataset, create string parameter for database name field

[image]

Create New parameter in dataset

[image]

Assign dataset parameter to Linked service parameter, which we will then use to store the data from trigger.

[image]

Create or use existing trigger, I am using a custom event trigger for example

[image]

A custom event trigger can parse and send a custom  `data`  payload to your pipeline. You create the pipeline parameters, and then fill in the values on the  **Parameters**  page. Use the format  `@triggerBody().event.data._keyName_`  to parse the data payload and pass values to the pipeline parameters.

For a detailed explanation, see the following articles:

- [Reference trigger metadata in pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-trigger-parameterization)
- [System variables in custom event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#custom-event-trigger-scope)

[image]

existing pipeline parameter.

[image]

Inside pipeline activity, specific your activity when used in source it would prompt for dataset parameter. Here use dynamic content and select the parameter holding trigger data.

[image]

[image]

**Finally**.. when the pipeline is triggered, trigger metadata is passed to pipeline parameter, which will be used in dataset property to switch between database dynamically in a server. Use multiple parameters similar to my example for use in different triggers and pipeline as per your environment.