# How to use datasets and linkedServices in Web Activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone give me a complete example about using this two properties?

[image]

And there is something weird in the [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity).

```json
{
    "body": {
        "myMessage": "Sample",
        "datasets": [{
            "name": "MyDataset1",
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }],
        "linkedServices": [{
            "name": "MyStorageLinkedService1",
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Why pass strings, and it seems not working?

Comment: could you please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093957/send-parameters-in-trigger-adf/69097919#69097919 - if it suffice as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you would want to pass the Dataset's or the LinkedService's Json code to your API, you have a provision through **WebActivity** under **settings** fields `Datasets` and `Linked services`.

Practically I haven't come across such a scenario, but below is one such possibility.

If you want to create ADF pipelines, datasets, linked services using REST as explained here [Create linked services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-linked-services) & [Create datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-datasets)  Also, these can be passed into the call as an array for the receiving service.

Check out the below example, where you can create new sql linked service and dataset with scaled Azure SQL Database refering and existing one. Similarly, you can also use Blob storage linked service to pass file name received from trigger as parameter to rest API.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]