# Azure Data Factory Uploading file using REST Multipart/form-data

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory

I am calling a REST endpoint which takes a file as multipart form-data as the body. Here is the postman CURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://assets-api-uat.test.services/api/upload' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'loadType: DELTA' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}' \
--header 'Cookie: ARRAffinity=6d69fc278349240ce92e5954e0b0d0f1ee5c6964839ee2281238f950751dbfa5; ARRAffinitySameSite=6d69fc278349240ce92e5954e0b0d0f1ee5c6964839ee2281238f950751dbfa5' \
--form 'upload=@"/C:/Users/test/Downloads/testhazards.zip"'
```

The above works fine.

I am trying to implement the above using Azure Data Factory as below
[image]

However the Azure Data Factory gives Bad Request error (400). How do I specify the "upload=filename" in the web activity?

Below is the changes based on the suggested answer

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way around this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

This is not suppored by Azure Data factory. To workaround this you could extend ADF with function apps, container apps or maybe by using [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity).

---

After reading documentation and other answers there is only one answer.

Multiple answers suggests using **Web activity** and selecting dataset or using copy data activity with **REST** dataset/linked service.

**Web activity** simply will not work: instead of dataset data only metadata is being sent to API.

**REST** sends data as JSON playload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-sink => No muli-part form wrapper or other formats supported.

---

Extra info for OP and all having issues with **activity outputs**:

**Copy activity's output** does not include actual data. Only results(elapsed time, speed, mount of copied data etc) of he activity execution. Actual data movement is from source to sink.

[**Lookup activity**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) can be used to read dataset data into ADF pipeline but it has limitations:

- only 5000 rows
- and max size 4 MB

Answer (score -1):

You can pass datasets and linked services to be consumed and accessed by the activity. In the **Settings** tab of the web activity, `Datasets` property represents the list of datasets passed to the endpoint.

[image]

You can refer to this sample [Request payload schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#request-payload-schema) from MS docs:

```
{
    "body": {
        "myMessage": "Sample",
        "datasets": [{
            "name": "MyDataset1",
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }],
        "linkedServices": [{
            "name": "MyStorageLinkedService1",
            "properties": {
                ...
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Checkout a [Similar ask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400725/15969417)

Comment: Not much luck on this.  This is the error message and I have updated the question.
Error calling the endpoint 'https://assets-api-uat.test.services/api/upload'. Response status code: 'Unknown'. More details:Exception message: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'.

Comment: Those dataset and linkedset selections only injects metadata of the selected datasets and linkedservices into HTTP body JSON. No actual data is being sent.