# Upload a file attachment using Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I’m trying to replace some source python code to upload a file to a REST service as an attachment to a POST request, using a Web Activity and/or a Copy Activity in ADF.

In the source python code, it’s trivial. The essence is this:

```
 url = 'https://targetrestservice.com /rest/api/10/data'
 files = {'file': (REPORT_FILENAME, open(REPORT_FILENAME, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
 headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(MY_API_KEY)}
 r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

I’ve tried configuring the Web Activity and the challenge is that the target server only ever sends a helpful 500 service error in response. So it knows something is wrong but isn't telling me what. I've been looking at the requests by using webhook.site to see the requests.

I’ve also tried using a Copy Activity and using the file (which is a CSV) as an attached dataset. But that doesn't send it as an attachment. It just puts the contents of the file in the body of the request.

Anyone know if this is this meant to be achievable in ADF using the Web Activity?

I presume I could do this via executing a python notebook as part of the pipeline, but that really seems like “using a sledgehammer to crack a nut”, and would add large ongoing expense for the databricks or batch clusters.

Comment: What does each of the key and value for the variable files mean? `files = {'file': (REPORT_FILENAME, open(REPORT_FILENAME, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}`

Comment: REPORT_FILENAME is just the name of a variable that holds a file name i.e. the file that's being uploaded. I've got it basically working now against a test web api, but of course the one I need to talk to doesn't give any help, just a 500 Internal Server Error response. I had to hand-craft the required headers and body and it now looks like a file upload on a POST, but the remote server still doesn't like it.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the rest web api thats working is with data factory web activity or with python?

Comment: The main web api was being called from python. I'm trying to migrate the code to native ADF web activity calls. I've now got file uploads, etc. working, but am still struggling with the actual API but that's because the server doesn't give a hint as to what the problem is. It's probably worth closing this question now.

Comment: Not supported by ADF. See my answer on other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78052466/776884