# Using a Web activity along with a linked service to call a rest api

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to send data to a rest API via data factory.
I get batches of records from a database, send them in the body of the REST API call, which provides a response that informs the action performed on each record.

I created a linked service to the base API URL, and this linked service does the authentication to the API.

My question is how I use this linked service along with a web activity in a pipeline?
The web activity requires me to enter a full URL, which feels redundant as the base URL is already in the linked service.

The web activity does let me add multiple linked services but I'm unsure why it allows multiple linked services and how this is supposed to work.

I would appreciate expertise regarding how the web activity works with a linked service.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to share a screenshot of what your pipeline looks like? Is your linked service a linked service reference? In web activity, you can pass linked services as part of the payload (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)

Comment: please check this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299963/how-to-use-datasets-and-linkedservices-in-web-activity